# MERCHANT.ONBOARDING.COMPLETED webhook not being triggered

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I'm trying create a listener for the `MERCHANT.ONBOARDING.COMPLETED` in my sandbox environment. After the user goes to the return url specified in "partner_config_override/return_url" of the `/v1/customer/partner-referrals endpoint`, the webhook isn't being triggered, even though I received

`{"success": {"merchant_id": "GKH5BSPUXXB3Y", "tracking_id": "abcd", "products": [{"name": "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT", "status": "ACTIVE"}], "payments_receivable": true, "primary_email_confirmed": true}}`

when I call this endpoint to check if the seller has been onboarded: `/v1/customer/partners/{partner_merchant_id}/merchant-integrations/{seller_merchant_id}`. Are there any other steps I need to take in order for the `MERCHANT.ONBOARDING.COMPLETED` webhook to be triggered? The `CUSTOMER.MERCHANT-INTEGRATION.SELLER-ONBOARDING-STARTED` is being triggered and I do receive POST requests for that.

Comment: Appears to be a PayPal issue

Comment: @PrestonPHX in that case what would be my best option if paypal's apis dont work? should I just not rely on the webhooks?

Comment: Might be sandbox only, and should become resolved. Regardless, it is always good to amke use of API responses where possible and minimize reliance on webhooks. (this does not mean ignore webhooks)